# Git repo doenst contain a Solution(.sln) file. How can I get it to work?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, solution

When I clone the repo I want to add a C# project in visual studio. But I cant seem to build the project, since its not in a solution folder. How can I add an Solution folder to an already existing git repo consisting of some projects?

Comment: Why do you need a folder? I'm really not clear what you are asking here. Perhaps speak to the person who made the repo, maybe they just forgot to include the sln file.

Comment: Can you share the build error you are seeing? It should not be related to a missing sln file but we can discover it

Comment: Make Sure, Your Visual Studio Project and project cloned from Git are same. Mostly It happens

Answer (score 1):

If your file structure is like:

```
.git/
Project1/Project1.csproj
Project2/Project2.csproj
```

You go to the project root, and run the following in your powershell prompt:

```
# Create a new solution file
dotnet new sln

# Add all csproj files to it
dotnet sln add (Get-Item **/*.csproj)
```

You may now open the `*.sln` file directly within visual studio.

Comment: You're assuming two things. 1 - that it is a .NET Core projects. and 2 - the OP wants to add the sln file to the repo.

Comment: @DavidG yea... I did assume 1. the OP asked for 2 tho...